# SharePoint Online - Training

Tags: sharepoint-online, training

Is there any SharePoint Online training for IT users? Topics like: Lists, Columns, SharePoint structure, site collections, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for free training, classroom training, instructor-led training on-site? Lots of options available.

Comment: Free training. Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the articles from Microsoft official web site as below:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-video-training-cb8ef501-84db-4427-ac77-ec2009fb8e23

View the videos to start the SharePoint Online and click the links in this article for other topics.